# Как в php в функцию передать аргумент из js?

Tags: php, javascript

Такой вопрос интересный назрел, как и можно ли вообще так сделать, чтобы передать в php функцию аргументом js переменную?...

```
/* файл index.php */ 
<div id="box"></div>

<?php
    function getNum($num){
        return $num*5;
    }
?>
<script>
    var a       = 5;
    var html    = <?php echo getNum(/*как сюда вставить переменную a из js?*/); ?>;

    $('#box').html(html);
</script>
```

Пытался в getNum просто закрыть php, вставить переменную js и вновь открыть php  - но ошибку так бьет. Как правильно это сделать, и можно ли так?

Comment: ajax нужно использовать, не выйдет так сделать как у вас, потому что сначала работает PHP на сервере, потом он отдает результат в браузер, где работает уже js

Comment: а вот с php в js, то есть наоборот можно такое сделать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**PHP** работает с сервером, а **Javascript** с клиентом, по-этому Вы не можете использовать одну и ту же переменную в скриптах этих двух языков без передачи этой переменной на сервер с клиента. Но, Вы можете указать переменную **PHP** в переменную **JS**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var foo = '<?= $foo ?>';
</script>
```

Чтобы отправить переменную **Javascript** в код **PHP**, Вам надо использовать `ajax`. Это будет выглядеть как-то так [*(самый простой пример)*](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/):

```
var variableToSend = 'foo';
$.post('file.php', {variable: variableToSend});
```

На сервере Вы можете получить переменную в массиве `$_POST`:

```
$variable = $_POST['variable'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Нельзя! PHP выполняется на сервере, а js на клиенте. Если результат выполнения js скрипта влияет только на html (то-есть на DOM)  в этом нет необходимости, и логику изменений для элементов нужна продолжать писать на js, а если данные нужна обрабатывать на сервере(выполнить действия с базой, сессией, coockies) то-есть результат выполнения js влияет на дальнейшие состояние данных после перезагрузки страницы, то нужна передавать на сервер запросом через ajax или как элемент формы которая будет отправляться юзером.